# Use Jquery to take out url info from dynamic link - drop downs

Tags: jquery, url

Good day,  I have two drop downs.  One loads in the data for the second.  Once the user selects an option on the second dropdown, the page automatically forwards to that link.

I am trying to remove some elements from the url the drop down directs to:

> **http://local.mysite/someplace/county/north-hempstead-ny/orange/gardnertown**

I want

> **http://local.mysite/orange/gardnertown**

I have already figured out that
`window.location.href.split('/')[2]`  gives me what I want.  However the drop down selection part is throwing me off.

This is the part that needs fixing i think:

```
window.location.href.split('/')[2] + $places
      .append("<option value=" + this.url + ">" + this.community + "</option>");
```

Here is a  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/latoyale/zQ2VS/2/).

---

Thanks for the responses.  I tried to add the code but it still doesn't strip out the extra url text.  The console is not showing the stripping either.  Here is my revised code:

```
   document.getElementById('page-changer').reset();
$("#county").change(function() {
    var $places = $("#township").empty();
    $.each(data[$(this).val() - 1], function() {
        $places.append("<option value=" + this.url + ">" + this.community + "</option>");
     $('#jumpSubmit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
       window.location = window.location.href.split('/')[2] + '/' + $('#township').val();
      //console.log(window.location.href.split('/')[2]) + '/' + $('#township').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the value from the `<select>`

```
var $full_url = $("#your_select").val();
var $part_you_need = $full_url.split('/')[2];
alert( $part_you_need );
```

Comment: Thank you, this code will give me the section I need.  However I am not sure how to integrate this into my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to build the URL however you like based on your select elements. For example:

```
$('#jumpSubmit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = window.location.href.split('/')[2] + '/' + $('#township').val();
    //console.log(window.location.href.split('/')[2] + '/' + $('#township').val());
});​
​
```

*Updated code to use existing URL vs hard coded URL.*

Comment: You forgot to add `var url=window.location.href.split('/')[2]`

Comment: @juzerali - No I didn't. I'm not using that to build the URL.

Comment: Then where is `url` coming from?

Comment: @juzerali - Whatever the OP wants it to be.

Comment: I added this function to the bottom of my code.  Unfortunately, its not working.  It is still forwarding without stripping out the extra url info.  I edited the code above to show my new code.

Comment: Do you need to pull the URL from the browser or can you just specify it in a string?

Comment: I don't think I can specify it in a string since the host name does change with user's selection.  It has to come from the browser